# Get COUNT of id when GROUP BY Id and DATE

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

Currently, I have a table with 3 columns with `id`, `clicks` and `dates`. Every id has an entry with clicks for each day of a month with the format like '20180420' in the date column, let's say for 20th April 2018.

```
SELECT 
   id,
   month(date),
   COUNT(id) 
FROM mydb 
WHERE (date >= 20180101 AND date < 20180424) clicks > 0
GROUP BY id, MONTH(date);
```

I run this query to get if I have more than one clicks each month for this id and I want to do something like that to get the count of how many months every id has more than one clicks, but I don't get the correct result.

Am I missing something basic?
P.S: I am using `MySQL 5.6`

Comment: Add a sample and expected data to your question.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the correct solution. I needed to create a subquery since i wanted to group by after all. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I guess the date is stored as a varchar, if so then convert string into date.Try this:

```
SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(A.date,'%y%m%d')) MONTH, COUNT(*) NUMBER_OF_CLICKS
FROM mydb A
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(A.date,'%y%m%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('20180101','%y%m%d') AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: Actually I use MONTH() function from mysql but my main concern is that the count doesn't show correctly the number of ids that have more than 0 clicks